# Dependant drop down list based on multiple dropdown list in google sheets

Tags: validation, google-sheets, drop-down-menu, dependencies

I have a google sheet in which I have 3 drop down fields. In the first 2 dropdown list, the values are only Yes and No but based on the combination selected, I have to auto populate the values in the third drop down list. I have used the Query formula but unable to get the value in the third list. Below is the link to the sample sheet. Thanks in advance.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wbew4MA35UBp3wk2AQ1gnVdR7-88NCAZz9uB6lx7Qu8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

### Workaround: Use Filter() and Helper Columns

As a workaround, you may want to use helper columns. On the first 3 columns, place your table of combinations. Then, place the following formula to D2:

> =ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(C2:C, (A2:A=E1)*(B2:B=F1)))

Afterwards, place dropdowns with Yes and No as options to E1 and F1. As for the output dropdown, set it up as follows:

[image]

### Output

The sheet should look like the following based on the options:

**Yes-Yes**

[image]

**Yes-No**

[image]

**No-Yes**

[image]

**No-No**

[image]

If you wish, you may hide columns A to D since these columns are just helper columns.

### References

- [Create an in-cell dropdown list](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)
- [FILTER function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en)

### UPDATE

If the fraction values are detected as dates instead of decimals, then you might as well use decimal values on your combinations table:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the revert. The formula worked properly for getting the values in the third drop down list. However when I select 1/4, 1/2 or 3/4 in the third drop down list, the value gets changed into date. I tried formatting the cell to number but still it does'nt function. I have to use that value in calculation to get the value in another cell.

Comment: How about using decimal values in the combinations table instead since google sheets detects your values as dates?

Comment: Unfortunately I have to display it the way it is. Is there a way I can define in the calculation that if 1/2 is selected in the field than devide the number by 0.5. Something like this. Example; as per the above scenario, if in G2 I have selected 1/2 and my calculation formula in H2 should be 100/G2 then the value in H2 will be 50.

Comment: Unfortunately, your new request already counts as another question/post since the issue of your post `unable to get the value in the third list` was already addressed.

Comment: Fortunately, there is another post that answers your new request. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/105302/how-can-i-prevent-google-sheets-from-changing-fractions-into-dates#:~:text=To%20stop%20Google%20Sheets%20from,will%20simply%20leave%20it%20alone.